# Уровень звука Java приложения одним параметром

Tags: аудио, java

Доброго времени суток, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли в Java возможность задать общий звук для любого потока, т.е. грубо говоря чтобы управление звуком осуществлялось одним единственным параметром?
Приветствуется любое предложение, вплоть до самописного, библиотеки и т.д.

Comment: Не уверен на все 100, но возможно javafx поможет...

Comment: Каким образом в готовом приложении с уже готовыми потоками мне поможет javafx? O_o

Comment: Простите за некомпетентность. На всякий случай предложил :)

Comment: Я правильно понял, вам нужна программа, которая может регулировать звук для любого приложения в пределах одной JVM?

Comment: либо программа, либо алгоритм...<br>
Суть в том что она будет запускаться не как отдельное приложение...

Comment: А почему вас не устраивает регулировка для каждой линии?

Comment: Давайте предположим, что у меня открыто 10 потоков, иногда, конечно, удобно настраивать звук для каждой линии отдельно, но если элементарно просто надо притушить все приложения, прикручивать по 1ой линии?:)

Comment: раньше думал, что для этого придумали кнопки тише/громче на колонках =)
а вообще, если многопоточное одно приложение - тогда просто параметром можно указать, а если на всю JVM я думаю это надо ковырять ее "тонкие" настройки или лучше найти в ОС регистре параметр который отвечает за громкость от JVM 

Comment: Если бы меня устраивала кнопки тише громче ОС-мы я бы не задавал этот вопрос... Вот вы написали что можно параметром указать, вот как это реализовать?

Comment: Не скажу точно, я просто предположил, что надо ковырять в сторону настройки JVM, так как можно увеличить размер ОЗУ ВМ или поменять алгоритм сборщика мусора, причем остается вероятность, что такой настройки звука там не предусмотрено, потому мне кажется, лучше и проще ограничивать звук ВМ в ОС на которой она стоит.

Comment: JVM по определению не может иметь настроек громкости. JVM только генерирует и выполняет код.

Comment: Ну вы хоть понимаете, что вам надо программу, которая нарушает принцип инкапсуляции данных?  
п.с. Я со звуком не разбирался, но думаю можно попробовать перегрузить classloader и при загрузке класса, который отвечает за работу со звуком, пихать свою реализацию с dirty-hack'ом для регулировки из вашего приложения. Других идей нет.